# How to save the output of show version while running the script using python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a script that executes a command if a certain flag is True, and I want the output of the command to be printed into a text file. This is what I currently have:

```
if acco:
    uut.execute('show radius statistics')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use something like:

```
f=open("some_file.txt", "a+") # opens file in append mode
f.write(uut.execute('show radius statistics')) # appends data to file
f.close() # close file
```

Comment: I have two files which has a line "AAA SMU Testing-1". how to compare those two files and match that particular string which is in middle line of those 2 files?

Comment: You may want to open a new question. I'll be happy to help you, just post the question's link here.

Comment: I am to able to post the question. I should wait for 3 days it seems

Comment: I'm sorry to hear that, I didn't know